# DB2 on Cloud - DB Schema name with ending space

Tags: select, db2, ibm-cloud, database-schema

I have a database on **DB2 on Cloud** and DB Schema name *contains ending space* when I generate DDL via *db2look* or in *DBeaver*:

```
         CREATE TABLE "DBS_AA "."TABLE1"  (
                       "ID" INTEGER NOT NULL , 
                       "DATE" DATE
                       )
```

BUT all these SELECTs work fine:

```
         SELECT * FROM "DBS_AA "."TABLE1" 
         SELECT * FROM "DBS_AA"."TABLE1" 
         SELECT * FROM DBS_AA.TABLE1
```

So the questions are

1. Why there is a space at the end of the DB Schema name (not sure db2 admin did it)
2. Why all SELECTs works? Even if I did not use a space for the schema name.

Thanks!

Comment: Interesting. DB2 LUW 10.5 on premises does not behave like this. Spaces are significant. What specific edition/version are you using?

Comment: DB2/LINUXX8664
Database version:11.5.7.0.00000.012

Comment: And how is it configured? With Oracle compatibility? Any other options?

Comment: Oracle compatibility:no